# Angular 5 Child component exposes properties but not methods

Tags: javascript, angular

Any idea why I can get hold of all child component properties but not any of its methods?

I need to call a method on the child component (without using a service or an eventEmmiter) to validate its state and return a property.

**Parent**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class MyParent {
    @ViewChild('childEl') childEl: PhoneInputComponent;

    getChildValue() {
        const value = this.childEl.getMyValue();
        console.log(value);
        console.log(this.childEl);
    }
}
```

**Child**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'phoneinput',
    templateUrl: 'phoneinput.html'
})
export class PhoneInputComponent {

    private onKey = new Subject<string>();
    @Input() phone: string;
    private errorMessage: string;

    getMyValue() {
        return 'hello from child';
    }
}
```

console.log of value:

> undefined

console.log of this.childEl:

> PhoneInputComponent{onKey{}:Subject{}, phone:null, errorMessage:null}

no way to make `getValue()` available

Comment: Please provides a working stackblitz

Comment: @ViewChild(PhoneInputComponent) childEl: PhoneInputComponent; should work, this is how i use it.

Comment: Show us the template that includes the `PhoneInputComponent`, and the code that calls `getChildValue`.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code

```
@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class MyParent {
    @ViewChild(PhoneInputComponent) childEl: PhoneInputComponent;

    getChildValue(){
        const value = this.childEl.getMyValue();
        console.log(value);
        console.log(this.childEl);
```

}

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v4qqtt